# How do I output an XML file using ElementTree in python?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm slightly confused about writing an xml file using the xml ElementTree module. I tried to build the document:
e.g.

```
a = ET.Element('a')
b = ET.SubElement(a, 'b')
c = ET.SubElement(a, 'c')
d = ET.SubElement(c, 'd')
```

How do I exactly take this, and write it to a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an instance of [`ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree) class and call `write()`:

> `class xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree(element=None, file=None)`
>
> ElementTree wrapper class. This class represents an entire element
>   hierarchy, and *adds some extra support for serialization to and from
>   standard XML*.
>
> element is the root element. The tree is initialized with the contents
>   of the XML file if given.

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(a)
tree.write("output.xml")
```

Comment: Just to make sure I'm doing this correctly. If I wanted to attach a value or variable to a tag would it  be:  b.attrib = value ,  b.tag = variable?

Comment: @Shan I think you mean the text of an element. In this case, it should be e.g. `d.text = "test"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can write xml using [`ElementTree.write()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) function -

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
a = ET.Element('a')
b = ET.SubElement(a, 'b')
c = ET.SubElement(a, 'c')
d = ET.SubElement(c, 'd')
ET.ElementTree(a).write("test.xml")
```

This would write to file - `test.xml` -

```
<a><b /><c><d /></c></a>
```

---

To write xml with indents and elements on newline , you can use - [`xml.dom.minidom.toprettyxml`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.Node.toprettyxml) . Example -

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xml.dom.minidom as md
a = ET.Element('a')
b = ET.SubElement(a, 'b')
c = ET.SubElement(a, 'c')
d = ET.SubElement(c, 'd')
xmlstr = ET.tostring(a).decode()
newxml = md.parse(xmlstr)
newxml = md.parseString(xmlstr)
with open('test.xml','w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(newxml.toprettyxml(indent='\t',newl='\n'))
```

Now, `test.xml` would look like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<a>
    <b/>
    <c>
        <d/>
    </c>
</a>
```